# Como alterar uma palavra especifica em um TXT por outra

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso alterar a configuração do servidor Zabbix que está nesse diretório `C:\zabbix\conf\zabbix_agentd.win.conf`

Preciso substituir a palavra: `hostname=` por `hostname=192.168.1.1`

Fiz esse, mas a parte abaixo do `hostname` não entendi aonde colocar o nome para procurar e aonde colocar a palavra que irá substituir. Estou usando Python 3.6

```
import socket
import re

hostname = socket.gethostname()

with open('C:\zabbix\conf\zabbix_agentd.win.conf') as f:
    for l in f:
        s = l.split('*')
        editar = re.sub(r"\b%s\b" % s[0] , s[1], editor)
```

Comment: E precisa do Python para isso? Não é melhor abrir o arquivo no editor e alterar?

Comment: eh pq vai rodar em várias maquinas esse script

Comment: E você já tentou fazer alguma coisa?

Comment: sim o script já esta pronto, só preciso saber algum modulo e o comando para procurar e substituir a palavra especifica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu código não faz muito sentido pro que você está pedindo. Você não precisa usar expressões regulares pro seu caso, e nem `split`. Basta o [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace), que é o método mais básica que faz isso e é uma função da classe `str`.

Além disso, mudar as variáveis depois de ler o arquivo em modo de leitura não muda o arquivo. Pra mudar o arquivo, é necessário abri-lo em modo de escrita (passando `'w'` como segundo argumento do `open`) e escrever seus dados com `write` ou `writelines`.

Suponhamos que meu hostname seja `'DESKTOP-PI3R74I'` e meu arquivo contenha o seguinte:

```
lalala
foo
DESKTOP-PI3R74I=
bar
foobar
```

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
import socket

hostname = socket.gethostname()
print(hostname)  # 'DESKTOP-PI3R74I'

# Abrir o arquivo em modo de leitura
with open('arquivo.txt', 'r') as fd:
    txt = fd.read()  # Ler todo o arquivo

    # Substituir hostname= por hostname=192.168.1.1 em todas as 
    # ocorrências no texto lido
    txt = txt.replace(hostname + '=', hostname + '=192.168.1.1')

# Abrir o arquivo em modo de escrita
with open('arquivo.txt', 'w') as fd:
    fd.write(txt)  # Escrever texto modificado
```

Comment: Legalll, muitoo obrigadoo por explicar ainda, mas não posso trocar o hostname para o ip, porque o script vai rodar em várias máquinas, usando o gethostname para pegar o nome da máquina e assim editando o arquivo de configuração do zabbix(no arquivo de conf do zabbix tem uma linha escrita hostname=srvacd, preciso trocar para a variável gethostname

Comment: @Estagiário basta modificar os argumentos da linha `txt = txt.replace` pra substituir o que quiser por outra coisa.

Comment: Perfeito, mt obrigado Pedro, ficou assim e foi:  txt = txt.replace('Hostname=', 'Hostname='+hostname), eu tinha tentado esse .replace mas ele nunca funcionava poq n sabia da parte do .write . To aprendendo python sozinho e com a comunidade daqui. Muito obrigado!!

Comment: @Estagiário fico feliz que tenha dado certo! Não esqueça de aceitar a resposta pra marcar a questão como resolvida se não houver mais dúvidas.